# How to insert scriptTag in reactJS Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have facebook script now i want to add it to Jsx page of my application when page load

please help me...

what to do

```
<script>(function() {
 var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
 if (!_fbq.loaded) {
   var fbds = document.createElement('script');
   fbds.async = true;
   fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
   _fbq.loaded = true;
 }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '6034631592572346119422348', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6031592119428&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

Comment: Why not add it outside the actual React code? I don't see why this needs to be part of your JSX component.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to achieve, it seems strange to

- start in javascript,
- use JSX (HTML generator)
- to put another bit of javascript in the DOM (HTML).
- The function of the code put in the DOM is to fetch more javascript code
- to add to the DOM.
- the fetched bit of javascript (facebook connect) creates HTML to put in the DOM

Real shortcut:

- use your browser to [connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js)
- copy/paste* whatever is there to your javascript file, and wrap it inside a `doMagicalFacebookStuff()` function
- call the function whenever you need it (could be inside some HTML, e.g. `<button onclick='doMagicalFacebookStuff()'>Click</button>`)

*'*if the disclaimer/ license allows it, otherwise Google how to use facebook connect.*